# Unmarshal json optional element Golang

Tags: arrays, json, go

The data I got are xlsx rows in this format: row 1 value 1 is the first cell (A1), row 1 value 2 is the second cell (B1) etc. Any cell can (but doesn't need to) contain styles e.g. Border, Fill etc. .Styles will be in curly brackets like in this data: `[[["row 1 value 1",{"Border":null,"Fill":{"arrFill":{"BgColor":"red"}},"Font":null,"ApplyBorder":null}],"row 1 value 2","row 1 value 3"],["row 2 value 1","row 2 value 2","row 2 value 3"]]`

How to unmarshal this data to get also the not neccessary style map?

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/s451HUOETm)

Comment: Not getting what json unmarshalling has to do with Excel files, but you clould use a pointer definition in your struct for the style part. If this is nil it was not unmarshalled.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is Excel or not, I need just a way to unmarshal data like this.

Comment: If it is not related to the problem you are trying to solve, then do not mention it as this makes the question easier to understand. Other than that, the proposal with the pointer variable is valid, I am using this approach for unmarshalling YAML files with optional elements

Comment: Unmarshal it in struct instead of `[]string` [example](https://eager.io/blog/go-and-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use the reflect package to check data types in the resulting array/map. It looks tedious, but seems that is the only way out. I have pasted below some quick and dirt, but runnable code to illustrate the same:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func parsePrintArray(y interface{}) {
    var dummy []interface{}
    var dummy2 map[string]interface{}
    if reflect.TypeOf(y) == reflect.TypeOf("") {
        fmt.Printf("%s ", y)
        return
    }
    if reflect.TypeOf(y) == reflect.TypeOf(dummy2) {
        x := y.(map[string]interface{})
        for ks, vi := range x {
            fmt.Printf("\ndumping for key %s ", ks)
            if vi != nil {
                parsePrintArray(vi)
            }
        }
        return
    }
    for k, yl := range y.([]interface{}) {
        if reflect.TypeOf(yl) == reflect.TypeOf(dummy) {
            fmt.Println("")
            parsePrintArray(yl.([]interface{}))
        } else if reflect.TypeOf(yl) == reflect.TypeOf("") {
            fmt.Printf("%v: %s ", k, yl.(string))
        } else if reflect.TypeOf(yl) == reflect.TypeOf(dummy2) {
            x := yl.(map[string]interface{})
            for ks, vi := range x {
                fmt.Printf("\ndumping for key %s ", ks)
                if vi != nil {
                    parsePrintArray(vi)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    x := "[[[\"row 1 value1\",{\"Border\":null,\"Fill\":{\"arrFill\":{\"BgColor\":\"red\"}},\"Font\":null,\"ApplyBorder\":null}],\"row 1 value2\",\"row 1 value 3\"],[\"row 2 value 1\",\"row 2 value 2\",\"row 2 value 3\"]]"

    var y []interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &y)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    parsePrintArray(y)
    fmt.Println("")
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the correct answer because it helped me to understand my problem. I conditioned the parsing of the interface.Thanks.